# androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar doesn't show up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, androidx

In my Android application, there is a single main Activity with two Fragments. in one of them, I want to create the InstantSearch.

I'm trying to follow the [InstantSearch guide](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/getting-started/android/) but the `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` doesn't appear at all.

Here is my layout file for this Fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:focusable="false"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:iconifiedByDefault="false" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stats"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/memory_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:context="com.memoryDiary.Fragment.MemoryFragment"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
            android:id="@+id/add_memory_fab_menu"
            android:layout_width="297dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"

            fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="50"
            fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
            fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
            fab:menu_colorNormal="@color/babyBlue"
            fab:menu_colorPressed="@color/red"
            fab:menu_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
            fab:menu_fab_hide_animation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
            fab:menu_fab_show_animation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
            fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
            fab:menu_icon="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
            fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333333"
            fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444444"
            fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66FFFFFF"
            fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
            fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
            fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
            fab:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
            fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
            fab:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
            fab:menu_labels_paddingBottom="4dp"
            fab:menu_labels_paddingLeft="8dp"
            fab:menu_labels_paddingRight="8dp"
            fab:menu_labels_paddingTop="4dp"
            fab:menu_labels_position="left"
            fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
            fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
            fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
            fab:menu_labels_textColor="#FFFFFF"
            fab:menu_labels_textSize="14sp"
            fab:menu_openDirection="up"
            fab:menu_shadowColor="#66000000"
            fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
            fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
            fab:menu_shadowYOffset="3dp">

            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/add_memory_fab_add"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_insert_comment_white_24dp"
                fab:fab_label="Create Memory"
                fab:fab_size="mini" />

            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/add_memory_fab_search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
                fab:fab_label="Search"
                fab:fab_size="mini" />

            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/add_memory_fab_logout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_logout_new_white_24dp"
                fab:fab_label="Logout"
                fab:fab_size="mini" />
        </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>


    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My app build.gradle file includes `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'` dependency.

In addition, I changed the style.xml file to have `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` instead of `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`.

What could be the reason for toolbar doesn't show up?

Thanks for helping.

EDIT: As @Mayur Patel say, I had the wrong constraint to my RelativeLayout and now the problem is that `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` doesn't appear.

Comment: You should set the width to 0dp so the constraints are matched, and use a NoActionBar theme

Comment: You are given wrong constraint you your relative layout

Comment: @TimCastelijns, I forgot to mention I use a NoActionBar theme. I fix the width mistake but it's still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You have given the wrong constraint to your RelativeLayout.

Try this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:focusable="false"
                app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stats"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/memory_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/stats">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/stats">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
            android:id="@+id/add_memory_fab_menu"
            android:layout_width="297dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:menu_animationDelayPerItem="50"
            app:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
            app:menu_colorNormal="@color/babyBlue"
            app:menu_colorPressed="@color/red"
            app:menu_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
            app:menu_fab_hide_animation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
            app:menu_fab_show_animation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
            app:menu_fab_size="normal"
            app:menu_icon="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
            app:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333333"
            app:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444444"
            app:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66FFFFFF"
            app:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
            app:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
            app:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
            app:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
            app:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
            app:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
            app:menu_labels_paddingBottom="4dp"
            app:menu_labels_paddingLeft="8dp"
            app:menu_labels_paddingRight="8dp"
            app:menu_labels_paddingTop="4dp"
            app:menu_labels_position="left"
            app:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
            app:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
            app:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
            app:menu_labels_textColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:menu_labels_textSize="14sp"
            app:menu_openDirection="up"
            app:menu_shadowColor="#66000000"
            app:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
            app:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
            app:menu_shadowYOffset="3dp">

            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/add_memory_fab_add"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_insert_comment_white_24dp"
                app:fab_label="Create Memory"
                app:fab_size="mini" />

            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/add_memory_fab_search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
                app:fab_label="Search"
                app:fab_size="mini" />

            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/add_memory_fab_logout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_logout_new_white_24dp"
                app:fab_label="Logout"
                app:fab_size="mini" />
        </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This gives empty space for the toolbar but it still not appears.

Comment: @DvirBarzilay Bro that empty space is your toolbar

Comment: So why I don't see the SearchView?

Comment: @DvirBarzilay It is in your design I don't know why you have taken ConstraintLayout with match_parent width and height in the toolbar

Comment: I just follow the [InstantSearch guide](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/getting-started/android/)

Comment: No. I still don't know why the SearchView does not appear in the toolbar. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @DvirBarzilay I think your question is different then this SearchView.